# Nginx ingress controller 400 error when request header is "too long"

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

**NGINX Ingress controller version:** 0.18.0
**Kubernetes version (use kubectl version):** 1.11.1
**Cloud provider or hardware configuration:** Azure (AKS)
**Install tools:** helm

**What happened:** The Ingress controller gives a 400 error with a certain GET when a request url/header is "too long".

**What you expected to happen:**
The request is passed on to the correct service and pod.

**How to reproduce it (as minimally and precisely as possible):**
We use keycloak for authentication. When a user logs in a GET is done with an access token that is generated by keycloak. The access token gives a user certain rights within the application. Users have roles that gives them other/more permissions. When a user has a lot of roles the access token get significally longer which causes the 400 on the ingres controller. With a user with less roles it works fine and we can see the GET request being passed on to the right service..

**Anything else we need to know:**
We already tried adjusting header buffer sizes etc from 4k to 8 and 16k but that didn't do anything.
I set the ingress controller loglevel to debug, but it doesn't give any more info on the 400 error.

Comment: Can you determine the *too long* of your case i.e. beyond exactly how many characters it returns a 400?

Comment: A request header with 2299 characters works, but one with 4223 doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We solved this issue by also setting the backend service, a Spring Boot service with embedded Tomcat, configuration with server.max-http-header-size: 64000. So the Nginx service and the backend service settings had to be raised.